# speeding up a sqlite query with a join to a virtual table

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables, `t1` and a FTS5 virtual table `vt1` with the contents of `t1`

```sql
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
   ...> SELECT Count(*) as num FROM t1 WHERE deleted = 0;
QUERY PLAN
--SEARCH TABLE t1 USING COVERING INDEX ix_t1_t1Id (deleted=?)
sqlite> SELECT Count(*) as num FROM t1 WHERE deleted = 0;
308498
Run Time: real 0.043 user 0.023668 sys 0.009005
```

As can be see above, the actual query takes ~43ms

```sql
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
   ...> SELECT Count(*) as num FROM vt1 WHERE vt1 MATCH 'foo';
QUERY PLAN
--SCAN TABLE vt1 VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 131073:
sqlite> SELECT Count(*) as num FROM vt1 WHERE vt1 MATCH 'foo';
80789
Run Time: real 0.047 user 0.008021 sys 0.009640
```

The actual query takes ~47ms. So far so good. But the problem occurs when I join the two tables

```sql
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
   ...> SELECT Count(*) as num
   ...> FROM t1 JOIN vt1 ON t1.t1Id = vt1.t1Id
   ...> WHERE t1.deleted = 0 AND vt1 MATCH 'foo';
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE vt1 VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 0:m
 --SEARCH TABLE t1 USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_t1_1 (t1Id=?)
sqlite> SELECT Count(*) as num
   ...> FROM t1 JOIN vt1 ON t1.t1Id = vt1.t1Id
   ...> WHERE t1.deleted = 0 AND vt1 MATCH 'foo';
80789
Run Time: real 26.218 user 1.396376 sys 5.413630
```

The answer is correct but the query takes more than 26 seconds! Of course, I would like to speed up this query by several orders of magnitude, but I would also like to understand why this join is causing the slowdown.

**update:** so, after much hitting of my head against the wall of sql, I came up with the following – as noted above, I really have two distinct set of queries I can do separately like so

Q1: (SELECT t1Id FROM t1 WHERE …) AS a

Q2: (SELECT t1Id FROM vt1 WHERE vt1 MATCH ‘bar’) AS b

Then, I can do the following -

SELECT Count(*) FROM a WHERE a.t1Id IN b

Of course, in reality, I don’t do this separately but all in one go to make a really messy SQL but a really fast query, a couple of hundred ms as opposed to > 25s

You might notice that in my Q2 above I MATCHed for ‘bar’ instead of ‘foo’. That is because ‘bar’ returns fewer rows than ‘foo’ does.
The problem remains when there are too many matches in the FTS query in which case the FTS query itself is slow, for example, with ‘foo’ which matches > 80K rows.

Now, one interesting point of comparison – the same kind of query (from the user point-of-view) against an ElasticSearch instance (that is, all the rows with ‘foo’ anywhere in the text) is very fast, in the order of sub-hundred ms. I realize it might be unfair comparing SQLite with ElasticSearch, but still. (Or, is it a fair comparison?)

Comment: This one is probably worth taking to the sqlite mailing list.

Comment: Show the actual table definitions, including any indexes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed up the call may be just two swap the table order in your join.

FROM vt1 JOIN t1 ON t1.t1Id = vt1.t1Id

From the SQLite documentation:

> The default order of the nested loops in a join is for the left-most
>   table in the FROM clause to form the outer loop and the right-most
>   table to form the inner loop

The other thing to note is that joining the two tables results in a nested loop.  Your two tables seem to be quite large.  Match also does a full text search.  You should see if you can use a "LIKE" command on one or more columns to get the same result.

@Ge3ng also says when you are joining with an FTS table, sqlite can no longer rearrange your query for optimization.  You could also try adding the MATCH to the join statement itself.

FROM vt1 JOIN t1 ON (t1.t1Id = vt1.t1Id AND vt1 MATCH 'foo')

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Tried both, but unfortunately, neither sped up the search at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already found a solution, but I had a similar problem and after reading a lot about it, also this question, I've came with a solution that works for me and I'd like to share it.

First of all, in my case I only have virtual tables!

Making a joining query between two virtual tables using fts5 it just doesn't go well. So what I did, is to make two simple queries, in the first, get the IDs of one table and after, use them as filter in the second table.

Example:

table dogs:

```sql
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE dogs USING FTS5 (id, name, dog_walker_id);
```

table dog_walkers:

```sql
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE dog_walkers USING FTS5 (id, name, age);
```

Get all dogs of a dog walkers where name starts with a:

First query:

```sql
SELECT id FROM dog_walkers WHERE name MATCH 'a*';
```

Let's say you get: 1,2,3,4

Second query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE id MATCH '1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4';
```

In my experience, WAY faster than a joining query

I hope it can help somebody :)

Comment: why are using only virtual tables? I can't imagine what the advantage is over using normal tables because you don't seem to be utilizing the power of full text search here